# unexpected results when combining conditions with AND and OR

Tags: mysql

I have a code, provided below, which selects and sums completed orders from woocommerce just fine (for user 254).

However, I would like to also add processing orders which has attribute "wc-processing".

I was not able to figure it out.

The 'wc-processing' is in same table and column as 'wc-completed', but I guess you have figured this out.

I tried to use OR operator, but it didn't return any result in the end.

```sql
WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' OR 'wc-processing' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
```

So finally the original code (which works with just wc-completed):

```sql
SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta as pm
            INNER JOIN wp_posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2 ON pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
            WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
            AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_order_total' AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
            AND pm2.meta_value LIKE 254
```

Comment: `WHERE p.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing')`

Comment: `pm2.meta_value LIKE 254` is (usually) equivalent to `pm2.meta_value=254`, except I think `=` can be faster depending on how many rows you have.

Comment: @Barmar works perfect, thanks!

Comment: recognize that `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`,  so when we combine those, we frequently need to use parens around some of the conditions to override the default order of precedence. Using the `IN` gets rid of the `OR`, so fixes the order of precedence problem.  Otherwise, wrapping the conditions in parens would have worked e.g.  `... AND ( ps='c' OR ps='p' ) AND ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note how MySQL processes this

```
WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' OR 'wc-processing' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND ...
```

is not how we might expect, if we don't understand how MySQL sees that.

The `OR` is a boolean operator, and doesn't have anything to do with the `LIKE` condition.  With MySQL, the boolean `AND` operator has higher order of precedence than `OR` operator.

The condition is evaluated as if we had written:

```
WHERE ( p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' ) 
   OR ( 'wc-processing'+0 <> 0 AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND ... )
```

Note that the string literal `'wc-processing'` is evaluated in a boolean context, which means it gets evaluated as an integer, 0 is FALSE and non-zero is TRUE (NULL is NULL, but 
we know the string literal is not null. We also now the string literal is going to evaluate as zero, it's going to be FALSE.

So the condition is going to be equivalent to:

```
WHERE ( p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' )
   OR (    FALSE 
       AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' 
       AND ...
      )
```

And that bit inside the parens after the `OR` with the `FALSE` in there, doesn't matter how many `AND TRUE` we combine with that, there's no way it's going to evaluate to TRUE

So that condition basically boils down to equivalent to this:

```
WHERE ( p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' )
```

is how MySQL sees it

---

It looks as if what we meant to write was:

```
WHERE (   p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed' 
      OR  p.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing' 
      )
  AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
  AND ...
```

Note that the parens specify that the conditions `post_status` get evaluated, and combined with `OR` first, before the `AND` condition

---

A more roundabout way to express that, to avoid some parens, would be to repeat the AND condition, something like this:

```
WHERE (  
             p.post_status LIKE 'wc-completed'
         AND p.post_type   LIKE 'shop_order'
      OR 
             p.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing'
         AND p.post_type   LIKE 'shop_order'
      )
  AND ...
```

But I don't like to do that. The parens have a higher order of precedence over AND and OR; so my personal preference is to just use parens to make the order of operations explicit, and not depend on AND being evaluated before OR.

---

If we don't need to use LIKE comparison (because we aren't including wildcard characters) we could do equality comparison to get an equivalent result

```
WHERE (   p.post_status = 'wc-completed' 
      OR  p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
      )
  AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'
  AND ...
```

As Barmar noted in a comment, we can avoid the `OR` by using the `IN` operator. If we are guessing correctly at what was meant in the original SQL, we could write:

```
WHERE p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
  AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'
  AND ...
```

a commonly used pattern

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Now I believe I underestand SQL a bit better. :)